# Does weak convergence of filtrations preserve progressive measurability?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, filtrations

Suppose on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ I have a sequence of filtrations $\mathbb{F}^n =(\mathcal{F}^n_t)_{t \geq 0}$ generated by Brownian motions $W^n$ for each $n$, and these Brownian motions converge almost surely to another Brownian motion $W$. Let $\mathbb{F} = (\mathcal{F}_t)$ denote the natural filtration of $W$. Then Proposition 2 of Coquet, Mémin, Slominski, *[On weak convergence of filtrations](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=SPS_2001__35__306_0)* says that $\mathbb{F}^n$ converges to $\mathbb{F}$ weakly. That is, for any $B \in \mathcal{F}_{T}$, the sequence of cadlag martingales $ \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{B}|\mathcal{F}^n_{\cdot}]$ converges to $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{B}|{\mathcal{F}}_{\cdot}]$ in $J_1$ topology.

Now suppose I have a sequence of $X^n$ which are $\mathbb{F}^n$ progressive for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If $X^n$ converges to $X$ almost surely, can I somehow conclude that $X$ is $\mathbb{F}$ progressive?

I think I would like to show that $X$ is also the limit of $\mathbb{E}(X^n|\mathcal{F}_t)$. It suffices to show that  $\mathbb{E}(X^n|\mathcal{F}_{\cdot}) -\mathbb{E}(X^n|\mathcal{F}^n_{\cdot})$ converges to 0. Any suggestions?